# Count roads crossing borders?

Tags: road, borders, crossing

I am looking for a way to count the number of roads crossing a national border in Europe. If possible, I would also like to decompose this result between regions (NUTS2 European regions). I am looking for a simple way to do it.

Comment: What data have you got? Or do you need us to help you get that too? What software have you got?

Comment: I haven't used this kind of data before. I just would like to know if it is doable. I would like to do it for roads, railroads, pipelines, electric lines and navigable ways. I also would like to compute all the bordering regions of all the European regions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

Using [OSM data from Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html) you will have the administrative boundaries and all the roads.  Simply load the data into PostGIS (there are plenty of tutorial of how to do that - other spatially enabled databases are available) and then select all roads that intersect the appropriate level of admin boundary.  The count of the selection set is the number you want.

You can perform a sequence of intersects for each national boundary or tag all the roads by country and then do a count of tags after a single 'global' select.

Just be careful to check whether roads have been split at the boundaries (which might well be the case).  If so, you might end up with a value twice as large as expected.  To account for this, select all the roads that intersect the boundaries.  Then dissolve them all.  Then split multi part to single part.  You now have roads joined across the boundaries and your intersect will give you the correct count.

If you already have some other data, assuming that it is vector data, the above approach will work just as well.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. Do you know if there are grids of railroads, pipelines, navigable ways, and electric lines as well ? Also, is it possible to compute the bordering regions of all the European regions ?